# How to get data from a specific column of selected item(s) in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have an ObjectListView and I need to get the value of a specific column of the row that has been clicked at.

For example:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsDue.png) *(I would put the image here directly, but I don't have the reputation to do so.)*

I need to get the Id from the row that I clicked on (doesn't matter where on the row I clicked - I mean on what column within the row).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SelectionChanged event and access the corresponding property of your model object from there. Assuming you model class is named *MyDataObject*:

```
    private void olv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (olv.SelectedObject is MyDataObject data) {
            // Access data.Id or whatever else you need
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For clarity of my answer, I've supplied a complete working example for you to use. This example creates the sample data, the data grid view, the windows form, then shows the windows form. It then responds to a mouse click which displays a `MessageBox` to show the clicked row's ID.

I assume you are using a `DataGridView` to display your data and that the data is represented in an array or list of objects. This can also be done using a `DataSet` with a `DataTable`, but for simplicity I'm using an array of objects.

The code that answers your direct question is in the `MouseClick` event handler where it sets the `selectedObject` variable:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        new MyData { Id = 1, Typ = "Prichozi", Castka =  500, Datum = new DateTime(2019, 4, 16), Ucel = "test" },
        new MyData { Id = 2, Typ = "Odchozi",  Castka =  250, Datum = new DateTime(2019, 4, 16), Ucel = "test" },
        new MyData { Id = 3, Typ = "Prichozi", Castka = 2000, Datum = new DateTime(2019, 4, 16), Ucel = "test" },
        new MyData { Id = 4, Typ = "Odchozi",  Castka = 3500, Datum = new DateTime(2019, 4, 16), Ucel = "test" },
        new MyData { Id = 5, Typ = "Prichozi", Castka = 5000, Datum = new DateTime(2019, 4, 16), Ucel = "test" }
    };

    var view = new DataGridView();
    view.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    view.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    view.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    view.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
    view.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    view.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    view.ReadOnly = true;
    view.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    view.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    view.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    view.MouseClick += (sender, args) => { 
        // This is where the magic happens
        var selectedObject = ((DataGridView)sender)
            .SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(dgvr => dgvr.DataBoundItem).Cast<MyData>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        // Show your result
        MessageBox.Show(
            $"Selected row with ID: {selectedObject.Id}",
            "Selection Notification", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Information,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
            MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly,
            false);
        };
    view.DataSource = data;

    var form = new Form { Width = 500, Height = 300 };
    form.Controls.Add(view);
    form.ShowDialog();
}

public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public int Castka { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string Ucel { get; set; }
}
```